# Complex Numbers.. Arghh

Tags: c++, signal-processing, dft

I am working on a project that requires me to take an input, perform an DFT (Discrete fourier transform) and then take the number of zero-crossings from these values.

I have coded an algorithm, but, it uses complex numbers and I don't know how to manipulate / perform calculations on them. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

vector< complex<double> > DFT(vector< complex<double> >& theData)
{
    // Define the Size of the read in vector
    const int S = theData.size();

    // Initalise new vector with size of S
    vector< complex<double> > out(S, 0);
    for(unsigned i=0; (i < S); i++)
    {
        out[i] = complex<double>(0.0, 0.0);
        for(unsigned j=0; (j < S); j++)
        {
            out[i] += theData[j] * polar<double>(2, (-2 * PI * i * j / S));
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector< complex<double> > numbers;

    numbers.push_back(128);
    numbers.push_back(127);

    vector< complex<double> > testing = DFT(numbers);

    for(unsigned i=0; (i < testing.size()); i++)
    {
        cout << testing[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Now if I wanted to perform for example:

```
if(testing[i] >= 0)
{
    // blah blah
}
```

Then it will return an error. Any ideas, or suggestions? Is it possible to create a DFT without using Complex Numbers?

Comment: What should it mean for a complex number to be larger than zero (unless it's a real number)?

Comment: Complex numbers can't be compared aside from equality and distance from the origin. You can treat them as points on a plane.

Comment: 1) There are libraries to do DFTs for you. So there's little reason to implement it yourself. 2) A DFT needs to take complex numbers on at least one side (input or output). So you can't avoid them. 3) Complex number arithmetic isn't really that hard to look up.

Comment: If you're asking if it's possible to create a DFT without using complex numbers, you probably shouldn't be writing a DFT.

Comment: What significance would you assign to “the number of zero crossings”? Where did you read about using these? As a zero crossing is not in general a reasonable concept for a complex-valued function, I assume there is some misunderstanding related to that requirement.

Comment: @MvG - Thanks for the reply. Basically, I'm trying to identify whether someone is saying either "Yes" or "No" and I've been told to: "Process each block for important characteristics, such as strength across various frequency ranges, number of zero crossings, and total energy." This can be done using FFT's, frequency filters etc, z-transforms etc.. But FFT's are really, really complicated to code.. So I was thinking I would use a DFT and then identify the number of zero-crossings.. Sorry, I'm researching this project, so my knowledge is lacking BUT I am learning :)!

Comment: Oof. I think you misunderstood the instructions. it wasn't Data->FFT->zero crossings. It was Data->zero crossings AND Data->FFT. See my answer.

Comment: @Phorce: “complicated to code”: that's why you'd use the FFTW library. The speed gain is considerable. “zero crossings”: Like Bjorn wrote, likely in untransformed input (time domain). But that depends on a lot of factors, including gender and mood of the speaker, phase relation of various frequencies, and so on. I suggest reading more on the subject before you start to code. Otherwise you'll likely be frustrated by the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever gave you your instructions wasn't telling you to count zero crossings on the results of the DFT/FFT. That would be meaningless. (If they were telling you to do that, they were clueless. You have my permission to laugh at them for giving you such ridiculous instructions). Rather they were telling you to count zero crossings on the original data, and also look at the FFT of your data.

However,

- Zero crossing rate is a pretty crappy starting point for speech recognition. Maybe you can get somewhere with it. With only slight hyperbole, I can say zero crossing is the least robust DSP analysis you can do. However, it is also simple, and speech recognition research has been going on a long time, so maybe there's some research on it. UPDATE/CORRECTION: this is a bit of a hyperbole. Actually I believe a lot of speech recognition techniques DO use zero-crossing, but you should know what you are doing first, because it's not very robust and sensitive to many kinds of errors like octave-errors. When you use zero-crossing, it's a good idea to low-pass (maybe aggressively) first. Definitely consider other factors.
- Understanding the output of an FFT is something that's asked so often here that I wrote a blog entry. Usually people are trying to track pitch, and you should do that, too actually, but there's other stuff you can get from the FFT like frequency centroid, and the relative strengths of different frequencies that are important in speech. Start here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html
- You might also want to consider simply filtering important speech frequencies (to find out what these are, start with wikipedia entry on ["manner of articulation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manner_of_articulation). For example, by following the link to Sibilant, you'll learn that "[s] has the most acoustic strength at around 8,000 Hz". Neeto!) You can get that info from an FFT or by filtering. There are advantages and disadvantages to each. You may want to look into the speech recognition literature to see what they use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still learning and researching, this is the first time I am branching out into Speech recognition (Wishing I hadn't, slightly ;)) I'll take a look at the links provided. I also need to implement an HMM somewhere for probability, could this be done with the FFT? For example.. DATA->FFT->HMM and then using a decision tree, identify the best fit for what someone is saying..

Comment: I don't think you need HMM for this simple problem. logistic regression or the like should be more than enough. Either way, it's a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to use HMM's to get the probability of what each phone could represent etc. Do you think this would be possible, in the solution identified.. Or, should I do some major reading?

Comment: Based on what I've read, that's definitely possible, though it's going a bit beyond my direct experience. I have solved similar problems with LR and it's much simpler.

Comment: Aha thank you :) Ok, I'm going to stay away from Zero-crossing. I'm going to strip the data for noise etc.. then run the raw data through an HMM to get the probability of each phone. Once I have found that, I can then determine if one of them matches the Phone "Y".. BUT quick question (and last).. Is there a reference for the different frequencies of Phones out there? I've looked but found nothing, wondered if you had come across any. Thanks :)

Comment: 1. I made an update about zero-crossing. 2. there is no such reference because no correspondence exists. Some phones are "pitched", and therefore have a detectable fundamental frequency, and others aren't. How the energy is distributed also changes over time for any given phone and varies depending on speaker and things like their tone of voice. There are a number of other complications, eg, when you whisper, "voiced" phones become unvoiced, but are still recognizable.

Answer (score 0):

[Fourier transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) such as [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) return [complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), so you can't really get around them.

Depending on your application, you *may* be able to safely ignore the imaginary portion of your complex number, and treat the output of your DFT as a sequence of real numbers.

There are plenty of operations you can perform on complex numbers. Some might be relevant to your application, some not. It is worth taking some time to better understand complex numbers.

Finally, **no**, it is not possible to create a DFT without using complex numbers. You can take the complex output of a DFT and transform it into real numbers, but you will lose information in the process. You need to understand complex numbers and how the DFT is being used in your application to be able to determine whether or not it is appropriate to perform any such transformation.

Comment: Re: ignoring the complex part: I would not advise that in his application.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and i gave up using a vector container for the c++ complex double numbers since it isn't well supported with FFT libs and ended up using a plain old array. You will find most of the stuff your trying to do will work just fine.

```
 std::complex<double>*  in=new std::complex<double> [N];
```

All arthmatic will work as it would with any other array for instance `abs(in[i])` or `in[i] *pi`  just make sure to use the C++ version of the math library

for your specific question you have to check the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/) there are real and imag functions you can use to see if it's greater then zero

then just make sure(if your using fftw)

to use reinterpret cast on all the complex numbers (input and output if they are complex)

```
    p = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N, reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(in), out,FFTW_ESTIMATE);  

   fftw_execute(p);
```

Comment: If you reinterpret a `std::complex<double>*` as `fftw_complex*`, you might just as well write `&v[0]` or `&*v.begin()` to obtain a pointer to the double array which holds the values of a vector `v`.

Comment: @MvG there's an issue with that. I don;t remember exactly what it is but the reinterpret_cast is what is suggested by the FFTW website

Comment: What do you mean with "it isn't well supported"? A vector doesn't care about what you put in it (as long as you can copy or — in C++11 — move it), with the exception of `bool`. So what doesn't work well, on which compiler?

Comment: @pyCthon Thank you for your answer. I'm basically trying to create a speech recognition algorithm and I don't know if DFT's are the right way to go now.. I need to count the total 0 crossings.

Comment: @Phorce do you mean number of (0,0)'s in a complex array? there are a few options you can print them all to a .txt or .csv file then check them with excel orwith a for loop `if(real(carry[i]) && imag(carry[i]) == 0)` if you want to check both or just check the real or imag values separately

Comment: Don't try to tease out the real and imaginary components and see if they cross zero as this answer seems to be suggesting.

Comment: @BjornRoche i was confused on his question as well

Answer (score 0):

A DFT will always use complex numbers, at least for its output. If the input describes some signal over time, then the output describes the signal according to frequencies. Each complex number may be written in [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) and then split into an absolute value which denotes amplitude and an angle which denotes phase. Perhaps it's the amplitudes you're interested in; if so, you'll want to compute abolute values, but they'll all be non-negative as well.

There are [variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fourier-related_transforms#Discrete_transforms) of a DFT which work on real numbers. The [discrete cosine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) comes to my mind in that respect. Not sure whether this is of any use in your application.

*Note* that there are libraries like [FFTW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTW) which may compute the DFT faster than your code would. Even a self-written [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) might be worth considering, as long as your input size is a power of two. But all of this is a bit beside the point of your actual question.